# PIP - 'module' object has no attribute 'CDLL'

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x, debian

**For anything I want to use "pip" pops up the following error:**

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/pep425tags.py", line 188, in have_compatible_glibc
     process_namespace = ctypes.CDLL (None)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CDLL'
```

Comment: I think it will be helpful if you can add more information about your environment. How did you install pip, python? Which debian version do you use?

Comment: I have Python version 2.79 and Python 3.4. I have a Debian version 8.